# Country City Population database

Tags: geospatial, city, database

I'm trying to do some research for some people in the SEO and data marketing industry.

I'm flat broke so I don't have money to spend but I would love to find a database that's free that just has the Country and all its cities or at least major cities and their recent population.

Comment: ....what country?

Comment: geonames.org ??

Answer (score 1):

Country population can be retrieived from (API available): http://api.population.io

City/Country population can be found here: https://www.citypopulation.de

Answer (score 1):

The UN report [The World’s Cities in 2018](http://www.un.org/en/events/citiesday/assets/pdf/the_worlds_cities_in_2018_data_booklet.pdf) lists every world city with a population of over 1 million people.

[World Population Review](http://worldpopulationreview.com/world-cities/starting-with-a/) lists many cities, including cities with populations under 1 million. You would need to go through each letter of the alphabet to get them all.